# How does "quid causae" work grammatically?

Tags: idiom, grammar-identification, interrogative

I do not understand the grammar of *quid causae* = "[for] what cause", as in

> Nescio quid causae fuerit, cur nullas ad me litteras dares
>
> I do not know what the reason was why you sent me no letters.

or

> Ego haud facile indagare valeo, **quid causae** exstiterit, quod tu me de canora musicae modulatione jubeas aliquid proferre.
>
> I can hardly ascertain **why** it might arise that thou biddest me to say something on the canorous mensuration of music.

What is the rationale?  Is it really no more than an idiom? But why is it not *quid causa* in the nominative?  Is it to be understood as, e.g., "why, for cause"?  Or is it that the whole phrase, including *quid*, is perhaps dative in sense and that *quid* had simply acquired an immutable form whenever it stands for "why"?  And, if so, when did the phrase first appear in this seemingly agrammatical form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Early attestations

In [Plautus](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=quid+causae+%5Bpl%5D) *(num)quid causae* is found three times (Pseudolus 533, Rudens 758, Trinummus 1188), every time with *est*.
There may be earlier attestations, but [Plautus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plautus) is pretty old and thus the construction is not a late invention.

I would rather analyze the idiom as *quid causae est*, including the verb.
Leaving *est* out is a common feature and would be no surprise.
In the first instance you quote there is indeed an explicit *est* (now as *fuerit*).
In the second example there is another verb, *exsistere*, which is pretty close to *esse* in meaning.
These with the three examples form Plautus suggests that the verb is a part of the phrase and it might be wise to understand an implicit *est* with *quid causae* when no explicit verb is supplied.

#### Quid and genitive

I suggest taking a look at the [Lewis & Short entry on *quis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DQ%3Aentry+group%3D9%3Aentry%3Dquis1), especially section II on the neuter *quid*.
Section II.A.2 gives several examples of *quid* together with a **partitive genitive**, the simplest being *quid mulieris uxorem habes?*, "what sort of a woman have you for a wife?".
Partitive genitive is common in many uses, and using it together with the neuter *quid* is a particular idiom.
Such use is not unique to *causa*, and the ample attestations indicate that the case in question is indeed genitive, not dative.

With this in mind, you could interpret *quid causae [est]* as "what kind of reason is there", which means "why".
But bear in mind that *quid* is quite a bit more flexible than the English "what".
It can stand for "why" alone.

#### In practice

The construction *quid causae est* is a little confusing so it may be simplest to treat it as a fixed idiom in practice.
It could be translated as "what is the reason" or simply "why", depending on context.